# How to Achieve a Strong Metallic Reflection Presence on a Scattered Material?

Tags: materials, node-editor, lighting, reflection

I am building a model which a piece of black paper is stamped with a reflective silver foil. This is being built in **Blender 2.83, using cycles render**. I have tried my best to set up a material for this, but I either get all black (where the foil needs to be) or an matt light grey.

I included a Environment texture to give it some reflections, but It lit up the black paper material to look light grey.

Roughly I am using a PNG Image texture as a mask for the 2 principal shaders. *1 for the paper texture and the other for the metallic silver foil texture.*

I guess I am trying to find a way to really light up these metallic surfaces without effecting the dark color in paper, Thank you.

> (Also if anyone knows a great tutorial on getting really sharp sleek
> lighting that would cut across a glossy surface nicely, I'm looking
> for one!)

### **CURRENT NODE GROUPING**

[image]
[image]

### **CURRENT RENDER RESULT**

[image]

### **Updated Render Results**

[image]

Comment: What render engine do you use? If EEVEE, did you enable screenspace reflections?

Comment: It's actually hard to tell because I don't know what textures and images you use for the bump, the alpha and the environment. Just by setting up the nodes like you did and using some random textures I've got here it looks a lot different to yours, the foil part not overall black. So your textures and/or blend file could be useful.

Comment: OK, Here is the .blend file:  https://we.tl/t-MNGTUGp0VH  : I'm honestly not suppressed you are getting a different result, I think I have my file set up incorrectly. In so many places, but can find a clean evergreen tutorial to set as my default.

Comment: First of all, your render looks that strange because next to the buttons where you can change the viewport shading like "Wireframe", "Solid", "Material Preview" and "Rendered" there is a dropdown menu.In "Rendered" mode there you can set the render pass you would like to see. For the "real" image it should be set to "Combined", you have "Glossy Direct" selected. The other thing is, since your HDRI is mostly dark walls with few lamps, the glossy foil parts have a roughness of 0 and the bump a strength of 1 the edges have a harsh highlight and the foil mostly reflects the black walls.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the render pass. But I am unsure what you are suggesting I should do about the HDRI, Roughness, Bump.

Comment: Well, if the foil should show more than black then there must be something to be reflected that's not black, so a different HDRI may help. The roughness:l if the foil should have mirror-like sharp reflections then 0 is fine, but it means if the environment is black with one bright lamp, the foil will always be black as long as the angle isn't directly reflecting that lamp - a roughness of 0.2 or 0.3 would spread the light over the surface. The problem with the bump at strength 1 is that it's no real displacement, and it creates a broad bright edge but still looks flat and strange.

Comment: I decreased the bump, and boosted the roughness, and changed the HDRI to a new brighter one. It really seems to help! Thank you! I also changed the noise texture. Do you think including the map directly to the material output displacement would show the real Hight change? Or do I need to make a texture map for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116151/discussion-between-nymex-and-gordon-brinkmann).